# Cannot read property 'bot' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.io

I'm trying to make a little and simple bot to delete messages (if they start with some specific characters) posted by users in a text channel. This is the code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');

//configure logger session
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, { colorize: true });
logger.level = 'debug';

//inizialize bot
var bot = new Discord.Client( { token: auth.token, autorun: true });

/*bot.on('ready', function(evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + '-(' + bot.id + ')');
});*/

bot.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    var msg = message.content;

    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.channel.id === 'CHANNEL ID')
       if(!msg.startsWith('!') && !msg.startsWith('gs.')) {
           message.delete();
           message.reply('In questo canale sono ammessi solo comandi per i' +
                         ' bot,riprova sul canale "generale"')
                  .then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(7000); })
       }
});
```

Here I substituted the real channel ID with *CHANNEL ID*, just to be sure to don't reveal possible sensitive data.

Comment: if(message.author.bot) return;... message.author doesn't exists

Comment: Are you trying to do: if message content starts with either '!' or 'gs.'... then delete the message and reply with 'In questo canale...' or the inverse? You want to delete and reply when the message content does not start with  '!' or 'gs.'?

Comment: @MattLong if the message DOESN'T start with "!" or "gs" the bot must delete it and then reply

Answer (score 0):

Delete & reply to message if it starts with either '!' or 'gs.'

```
bot.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
  if (message.author.bot || message.channel.id !== 'CHANNEL ID') return;

  const msg = message.content;

  const msgUnwanted = msg.match(/^!/) || msg.match(/^gs\./);

  if (msgUnwanted) {
    message
      .delete(2000)
      .then(msg => console.log(`Deleted message from ${msg.author.username}`))
      .catch(console.error);

    message
      .reply(`In questo canale sono ammessi solo comandi per i bot,riprova sul canale "generale"`)
      .then(sent => {
        sent
          .delete(2000)
          .then(msg => console.log(`Deleted message from ${msg.author.username}`))
          .catch(console.error);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: `message.author.bot` and `message.delete().reply()` is `discord.js` code. The Original Poster is using `discord.io` wich is not object oriented like `discord.js`